# Get node value from document

Tags: php, xml

I have XML in PHP, I am trying to get the value of the status node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<response>
  <result>
    <form name="MREP">
      <update>
        <criteria>
          <field name="Serial_Number" compOperator="Equals" value="A-000-1012"></field>
          <reloperator>AND</reloperator>
          <field name="MREP_Type" compOperator="Equals" value="0"></field>
        </criteria>
        <newvalues>
          <field name="Is_being_Used">
            <value><![CDATA[TRUE]]></value>
          </field>
        </newvalues>
        <status>Success</status>
      </update>
    </form>
  </result>
</response>
```

I tried

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($mrepValide); 
echo $xml->status;
```

(where $mrepValide is a string of XML shown above)

But I think it didnt work since status is not the parent node. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your XML only shows one line. Please attach a `var_dump` output of `$xml` in your original question so the structure can be determined and we can help you figure out how to reference `status` node.

Comment: My apologies, someone fixed it already, I forgot to add the 'code' bracket to the rest of the XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document structure is:

```
<response>
 <result>
  <form name="MREP">
   <update>
    ...
    <status>Success</status>
   </update>
  </form>
 </result>
</response>
```

So you must properly navigate it, like:

```
echo $xml->result->form->update->status;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/lQxOoF

Take the time to familiarise yourself with [*Basic SimpleXML Usage*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic), which shows you how to move around in and work with SimpleXML objects.

Comment: And I will look into Basic SimpleXML Usage, it will definitely help me out